# Low latency image streaming between Win11 and WSL2

Tags: python, c#, windows-subsystem-for-linux, shared-memory

I need to stream images from a C# application running on Windows 11 to a python module running on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04).

Please note that I'm not a networking expert - I do computer vision.

I've tried using WebSockets and am passing a 640x480 image to python and receiving a short string in response. Unfortunately, the round trip time is about 80ms, which is at least 75ms too long. When I pass a short byte array (100 bytes) through the WebSocket, the round trip time is about 1.5ms.

I can reduce the size of the image, but that's only going to get me part of the way there.

What alternatives do I have?

- I've considered using raw TCP/IP, but I'm concerned about my ability to build a robust server in python and a robust client in C#.
- I've used memory-mapped files for interprocess communication in the past, but I'm not sure how to share memory between windows and WSL ([Shared Memory Between Windows Process and WSL Linux Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312636/shared-memory-between-windows-process-and-wsl-linux-process))
- I'm seriously considering setting up a RAM disk, writing to file from C# and then opening it in python, but this makes me feel itchy.

Can anyone suggest anything better?

Comment: Are you sure the 80ms is in the actual transfer time, and does not include serializing/deserializing or any other processing?

Comment: I start timing when I send the data, read it into an array using np.fromstring then return a simple string. I stop timing when the reply string arrives. 80ms is the round trip time.

Honestly, I think getting the data out of the message _should_ count as part of the time, since I have to do it in order to use the data.

Comment: I'm not a python developer, and I have not used webSockets, but I would expect most network protocols to have some way to send a simple byte array. So I would investigate any lower overhead protocols before trying anything like raw TCP or shared memory.